# How to get @request_stack service in app/console context?

Tags: symfony, httprequest, console-application

I have services that require the `@request_stack` to fetch parameters.

Now, I want to expose certain functionality to console commands callable via `./app/console/`/. Yet in the context of an `./app/console`, there is no `@request_stack`, yet one can input arguments.

In order to resolve this issue, I am now creating basically two services, one basic, only waiting for the params, and one being able to use the `@request_stack`.

Yet I dislike that there are two ways for the data to be fetched in the request-based flow and via the `app/console`.

Hence I am wondering, as I am simply want the data that comes per default via the request to also be able to be inputted via console arguments:

Can I setup a custom request_stack to simulate a request during a console command?

Comment: While writing a custom command extending `ContainerAwareCommand` -- in both `execute()` and `configure()` methods you can have the request stack like `$this->getContainer()->get('request_stack')`. But one thing I don't get is - what is the use of `@request_stack` in command line commands!

Comment: @HimelNagRana Currently, my services fetches its necessary params via the request_stack. Now I want to set them via console arguments. In order to avoid huge refactoring, I am looking for a way to have my services as they are, hence creating a stack_request even though it's not the optimal solution.

Comment: Well in that case - as I mentioned you can access `@request_stack` in your custom command class and use that as you want.

Comment: Yeah, just create a new request with your parameters in the format you need and push that onto the request stack.

Answer (score 1):

When I was investigating this issue, I stumbled across request stack push method, where a warning was already in place in the doc block:

```
/**
 * Pushes a Request on the stack.
 *
 * This method should generally not be called directly as the stack
 * management should be taken care of by the application itself.
 */
public function push(Request $request)
{
    $this->requests[] = $request;
}
```

So while it would be possible to do it this way, I decided against the approach of my original question and to refactor my application instead.

I have created a `context` value object which just holds the parameter data:

```
/**
 * Context
 **/
class Context
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $countryCode;

    /**
     * Context constructor.
     * @param string $countryCode
     */
    public function __construct($countryCode = '')
    {
        $this->countryCode = $countryCode;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCountryCode()
    {
        return $this->countryCode;
    }
}
```

And a `ContextFactory` that creates the context with by the request stack:

```
class ContextFactory extends RequestAwareService
{
    /**
     * ContextFactory constructor.
     * @param RequestStack $stack
     */
    public function __construct(RequestStack $stack)
    {
        $this->setRequestStack($stack);
    }

    /**
     * @return Context
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return new Context($this->request->getCountryCode());
    }
}
```

(The `RequestAwareService` is just a helper class to more easily parse the request.)

I then defined the services in my Bundle `services.yml`:

```
context.factory:
    class: Kopernikuis\MyBundle\Service\Config\ContextFactory
    arguments:
        - '@request_stack'

context:
    class: Kopernikuis\MyBundle\Service\Config\Context
    factory:
        - '@context.factory'
        - create
```

Instead of injecting the `@request_stack`, I am now injecting my `@context` value object, which also had the benefit of reducing the hierarchy as now only one service parses the request_stack once, and I also noticed that certain functionality got much simpler as I could remove parameters from method calls, as they were all provided by the context object instead.

And in my custom commands, I can just replace my context

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    // @todo: use variable from InputInterface
    $context = new Context('fnordfoo');
    $this->getContainer()->set('context', $context);
}
```

With the newly gained knowledge, I strongly disagree with my original intent of trying to manually set the `@request_stack`.

Refactoring the code base to not necessarily require the `@request_stack` was a more solid choice.